# No puedo iniciar apache, "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly."

Tags: php, xampp

[image: Error]

Ya intenté cambiando los puertos "80" y sigue sin funcionar ¿Alguna ídea?

Comment: Relacionado: https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/all/puerto-80-ocupado-por-system-pid-4/5b4bb1fc-0b81-4af2-96c5-7890f6eb51dd

Comment: Los puertos estan ocupados, deberías buscar que los usa y corregirlo. Puedes revisar el log para ver que mas menciona.

Comment: `Ya intenté cambiando los puertos "80" y sigue sin funcionar ¿Alguna ídea?` El log dice que sigue intentando levantar el apache en el puerto 80. Explica en la pregunta qué has hecho para cambiar el puerto.

Comment: Lo edité en el documento "httpd.conf" cambiandole los valores. de "80" a "8080". Esto es lo que me aparece en error.log =[Fri Nov 06 02:34:19.268467 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 20312:tid 660] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Nov 06 02:34:19.380068 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 20312:tid 660] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0